# Change color of NavigationBar for the "More" tab?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

When you have more than 5 view controller in your TabBarController, a "More" view is automatically setup for you. Is it possible to change color of the navigationBar in this view to match the color I am using, instead of the default blue?

Comment: Have you already managed to draw the other items with a different color then? Private API? Since You set just one image of whatever colors from which two image states are automatically being generated by `UITabBarItem` so you have a white and blue-ish image.

Comment: Ow that's not what you really want, just ignore my comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK. I should not have trusted the docs completely. I found the answer a couple of minutes later by trying it out. The docs lists the moreNavigationController is a read-only property. But this works fine for me:

```
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

or

```
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

In case anyone was wondering.

Comment: The fact that the property is read only means you can't assign to it, not that you cannot change properties of the object it references.
You cannot do `tabBarController.moreNavigationController = something;`.

Comment: I wrote this blog post a long time ago for anyone interested: http://runmad.com/blog/2010/01/coloring-fun-with-morenavigationcontroller-and-it/

Answer (score 1):

I only know that this works:

```
yournavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

But I do not know if it works therfore.

Answer (score 1):

In your application `UIApplicationDelegate` put this:

```
self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackcolor];
```

Comment: There's no need to answer an already answered and accepted thread with the exact same code...

Answer (score 0):

putting

```
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:64/256.0 green:191/256.0 blue:23/256.0 alpha:1.0];
```

in my main app delegate worked